# NodeJS in OpenShift EADDRINUSE Error

Tags: openshift

Im creating a site with nodejs in OpenShift and cant make it work..

Im putting the ip and port that OpenShift give me in process.env but it raise EADDRINUSE Error any way

Here is my code..

```
http = require('http');
express = require('express');
utils = require('utils');
app = express();
server = http.createServer(app);
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';
port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8000;
server.listen(ip, port);
```

console.log('Server listening on ' + ip + ':' + port);

and here is the nodejs.log

```
Server listening on 127.10.26.1:8080
warn: error raised: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
```

If the port is IN USE.. how can I get an available port?

Thanks for your help!

PD: My English is no good, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE means that the port number which listen() tries to bind the server to is already in use.  Something is already using port 8000.  Either close that something else or try another port.

Also, I don't think your code and log output that you show is in sync ... one is 8000 and the other is 8080?

Comment: That's right because ip is `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8000`
that means that the ip that openshift is giving me is 8080 (`process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT == 8080`)